# Enumerate keys in Amazon SimpleDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I'm trying to enumerate keys in Amazon SimpleDB. In SQL, it would be something like:

```
select unique itemName() from domain;
```

I've searched around but didn't find any way to do this. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition, items in a domain are unique, so you were almost there:

```
select itemName() from domain
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK SimpleDB doesn't *do* `unique`, but apart from that:

```
select itemName() from mydomain order by itemName()
```

should work, and you can remove duplicates (if any) very easily, since you're getting the names in sorted order (e.g. `itertools.groupby` in Python, and whatever analogous mechanism in whatever is your favorite language).